# Transfer images between Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-api

Is there a way, using the Google Sheets API, to transfer images from one Google Sheet to another that have been added using `Insert > Image`?

I had a look at the possibilities of Importrange but there doesn't seem to be a way to transfer images using that.

Comment: It depends on how the image is added to the sheet. Through formula `=IMAGE`? Via `Insert > Image`?

Comment: The latter, Insert > Image

Comment: Attention reviewers: asking how to do something via a platform's built-in web API is _not_ "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more."  It's a perfectly on-topic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer:

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to retrieve images added through `Insert > Image` via Sheets API, so all you have are several roundabout ways, which will only be appropriate in certain circumstances.

## Feature Requests:

There are several feature requests in Issue Tracker regarding image handling in Sheets API, I'd suggest you to star these in order to keep track of them and to help prioritize its implementation:

- [Retrieve "Image in Cell" cell data on spreadsheets.get endpoint](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157888759)
- [Insert images to Sheets using the API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160631703)
- [Update OverGridImage to support BlobSource interface.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119800855)

## Workarounds:

#### Option 1. Set image through its URL:

If a URL of the image is available and you want to write the image to a specific cell (not `over cells`), you could just add the formula `=IMAGE(your-image-url)` to the desired cell via [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update).

Or, if you're open to using Apps Script, you could use [insertImage(url, column, row)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertImage(String,Integer,Integer)).

#### Option 2. Copy corresponding range:

If the image was added via `Insert > Images > Image in cell` and the destination sheet is on the same spreadsheet as the source sheet, you could make a [CopyPasteRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#CopyPasteRequest) or a [CutPasteRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#cutpasterequest) to copy or move the range containing the image to the destination sheet (see [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)).

#### Option 3. Copy the entire sheet:

If the image was added via `Insert > Images > Image over cells`, or if the destination sheet is not on the same spreadsheet as the source sheet, your only option would be to copy the entire sheet via [spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo).

Answer (score 0):

You can download a zip file with the sheet in html format using Google API. It will contain all images, no matter how were they added.

1. Get Your API Key, from Google developers Console
2. Get a File ID of a google spreadsheet with permissions set to "Anyone with the link".
3. Now you're ready to call the api (with curl or browser window):
   `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{FILE_ID}/export?mimeType=application%2Fzip&key={YOUR API KEY}`

- Remember to fill the above with Your FILE_ID and your API_KEY from google.
- This works only for files with "anyone with link" permissions, otherwise you'll have to authenticate first. (see my answer here: [How to send google-sheet data in an email keeping the formatting( colors) intact from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787132/how-to-send-google-sheet-data-in-an-email-keeping-the-formatting-colors-intact/70895381#70895381))