# Is there any API available for Retrieve images in the cell from a google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to Retrieve images in the cell from a google spreadsheet. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489282/retrieve-images-in-cells-using-google-sheets-api?noredirect=1&lq=1) question is already available. and I also referred to [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) documentation.  But, these both are no longer work. Does anyone suggests me API or provides any good documentation link?

**Edited:**

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pS4CsxnI0yWBggRnIZkOya9f7EwO5vaRuXhxeVPAMno/edit?usp=sharing) is my Google Sheet. I'm trying to retrieve A4 and A5. Which is I uploaded from local machine. I used [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/1pS4CsxnI0yWBggRnIZkOya9f7EwO5vaRuXhxeVPAMno/gviz/tq?gid=0) API. But It's given me the blank value. Is there any other API available for retrieving this both images?

Comment: It depends on how the images are added to the cell (e.g. via formula, uploaded from local, etc.). Can you clarify that?

Comment: @lamblichus I am grateful to you for replying to me. I Edit My Questions Please check.

Comment: Any update on this one??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer images between Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264840/transfer-images-between-google-sheets)

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to retrieve images placed using the "Upload" functionality. To retrieve via API, the image should be placed using

> =IMAGE("http://your.url").

So upload your image to a content server, get the URL and insert them to the respective cells using =IMAGE formula.
Now if you retrieve the grid data using `Spreadsheet.get` and locate this specific element in the array, you will get the cell value as =IMAGE("http://your.url"), you can parse this string to retrieve the image URL.

Comment: I'm trying to do Image Retrieve Without URL like an Image Insert in cell From Local PC. and I'm trying to fetch this image using angular and other platforms. Is it Possible?

Comment: I'm Successfully Retrieve the Image. If it is URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a zip file with the sheet in html format with all the images – using Google API. I belive it will be easy to parse it and to get the image you need.

1. Get Your API Key, from Google developers Console
2. Get a File ID of a google spreadsheet with permissions set to "Anyone with the link".
3. Now you're ready to call the api (with curl or browser window):
   `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{FILE_ID}/export?mimeType=application%2Fzip&key={YOUR API KEY}`

- fill in your FILE_ID and API_KEY from google.
- works only with "anyone with link" permissions, otherwise you gotta authenticate first. (more here: [How to send google-sheet data in an email keeping the formatting( colors) intact from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787132/how-to-send-google-sheet-data-in-an-email-keeping-the-formatting-colors-intact/70895381#70895381))